# Convert literal string union into an array type

Tags: typescript

Given the following object:

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
```

I would like to build a type that returns:

```js
type ObjKeysAsArray<T> = ?; // ObjKeysAsArray<typeof obj>: ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I thought about `(keyof typeof obj)[]`, but it would return `("a" | "b" | "c")[]`, which is not what I want.

Comment: The type system does not observe property order (e.g., the type `{a: number, b: number, c: number}` is the same as `{b: number, a: number, c: number}`) and union types are also not observably ordered.  So there is no way to get an ordered tuple type from `keyof typeof obj` that's guaranteed to give you the same order as `Object.keys(obj)`.